# Can I find the location of text in a Word document using OpenXML SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I would like to put some known text in a Word doc and programmatically find it's x,y location with respect to the document or page using .NET.  Is that possible?  I was looking at using the OpenXML SDK but I don't see a path to getting that to work.  Or could I use something like an image or bookmark to do this?

Ultimately I'm trying to save the Word doc as a PDF or image (using a library like Aspose) and overlay some content at that location.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on further research and general understanding of the XML structure of the docs, it doesn't look like this is possible.  I looked at the third party components from Aspose to see if they supported it and they don't from a Word doc, but it may be possible from a PDF.  So I thought I'd post a link to that info:
http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/420805.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I think it's helpful to point out this.

A solution is to put a placeholder text, find it it the document, replace it with an image and save.

[This is explained in detail in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19180076/4584870)